# Visualizing linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi so I have a question I've started learning about linear transformations and I'm kinda having trouble visualizing them, like if I have some function $f(x) = x^2$ or something like this always made sense to me I give this function some x and I get out some Y which is just gonna be a point $(x,y)$ but now that I have some linear transformation T it's like I give it some vector and then it just gives me some whole new vector right so that original vector doesn't per say have to be related to the function at all like obviously the transformation is being done on it but I give it some vector and that transformation could do literally anything to it and give me a whole new vector so is it okay to just visualize linear transformations as a space of just a whole bunch of vectors?

Answer (score 1):

In general it is challenging to visualize an arbitrary linear transformation since, for example the vectors involved may be of higher dimension than we can easily visualize. I would recommend trying to get a visual sense for some low dimensional examples to build intuition and not worry too much about visualizing anything higher dimensional. I would recommend checking out [this 3Blue1Brown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE) as a good start.